# Opencascade Android Studio

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opencascade

I am trying to build an  Android application on Opencascade with the help of below url.

http://www.opencascade.com/doc/occt-7.0.0/overview/html/samples_java_android_occt.html

Everything works fine except I am stuck in below errors :

```
07-12 17:13:09.711: E/occtJniViewer(16333): Error: native library "gnustl_shared" is unavailable:

07-12 17:13:09.711: E/occtJniViewer(16333):   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.opencascade.jnisample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libgnustl_shared.so"

Error: native library "freetype" is unavailable:

07-12 17:13:09.711: E/occtJniViewer(16333):   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.opencascade.jnisample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libfreetype.so"

Error: native library "freeimage" is unavailable:

07-12 17:13:09.711: E/occtJniViewer(16333):   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.opencascade.jnisample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libfreeimage.so"

Error: native library "TKernel" is unavailable:

07-12 17:13:09.711: E/occtJniViewer(16333):   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.opencascade.jnisample-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libTKernel.so"
```

I am not able to add `gnustl_shared` library and other `.so files`. Please suggest steps as the above link does not provide much detail about these.

Any help will be of great assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCascade does not provide any binaries for building an application.
Build your own .so binaries file for Android in Windows OS :

1. Follow the steps carefully given here [Building with CMake for Android](https://dev.opencascade.org/doc/overview/html/occt_dev_guides__building_android.html)
2. Use only `Freetype` that comes with Open Cascade installer. `FreeImage`and others are not required for this sample.
3. After successful configuration and generation of CMake files, follow the step 1 URL.
4. There will be lots of issues while creating binary files for Android. Follow the below tricks :

   a.    Error related to `declspec(dllexport) x`. It comes in 3rd party library freetype that comes with OCC inside `freetype-x.x.x/include/config/ftoption.h`. It can resolved by commenting out the line number (282 if OCC 7.0.0 is used) given in the error and entering `#define FT_EXPORT_DEF(x)  x` in place of it.

   b.    Use the make command to start building again.

   c.    Paste freetype.so in `freetype-xx/lib`. Copy libEGL.so from `..\android-ndk\platforms\android-xx\arch-arm\usr\lib` and paste it in `freetype-xx/lib`.

   d.    Open inc folder for CMake output folder given in step 1. Copy the contents in `..\android-ndk\platforms\android-xx\arch-arm\usr\include` and paste in inc folder. Follow step 4.b.

**NOTE** : android-xx depends on ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL. It can be android-15.

5. If no errors are there then continue to follow the step 1 URL.
6. After successful installation, go to CMake output directory and look for lib folder in any subfolders (may be lin32/gcc/lib). Inside lib folder all the required binary files will be there.
7. I've created the binaries. [download from here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0bzx0t25qpcfg97/AACdCNuRMQzCsNcqRL58e7l-a?dl=0) and copy the binaries in `jnilibs` folder in project.
8. Apart from freetype no other 3rd party library is required.

Now coming back to the question - `gnustl_shared` is not reuired to add as an external binary.

Inside `app\build.gradle` use below code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 24
        buildToolsVersion = "24.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.occ_poc_as"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 24
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName = "OcctJni_Viewer"
            cppFlags.add("-I${file(getOpenCascadeDir())}".toString())
            cppFlags.add("-frtti")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            stl = "gnustl_shared"
            toolchain = 'clang'
            ldLibs.addAll(['android', 'log', 'EGL', 'GLESv2'])
            cppFlags.addAll(['-Wall', '-std=c++11'])
            CFlags.addAll(['-Wall', '-std=c++11'])
        }

        productFlavors {
            // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
            // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
            create("arm7") {
                ndk.with {
                    abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                    ldFlags.add("-L${file('src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a')}".toString())
                    File curDir = file('./')
                    curDir = file(curDir.absolutePath)
                    String libsDir = curDir.absolutePath + "\\src\\main\\jniLibs\\armeabi-v7a\\"
                    ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libfreetype.so")



                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKBRep.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKernel.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKG2d.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKG3d.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKGeomAlgo.so")

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKGeomBase.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKMath.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKPrim.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKTopAlgo.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKBO.so")

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKBool.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKFillet.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKHLR.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKIGES.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKMesh.so")

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKOffset.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKOpenGl.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKService.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKShHealing.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKSTEP.so")

                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKSTEP209.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKSTEPAttr.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKSTEPBase.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKV3d.so")
                ldLibs.add(libsDir + "libTKXSBase.so")


                }

            }

        }
    }

}

def getOpenCascadeDir() {
    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(new File(rootDir.absolutePath + "/local.properties").newDataInputStream())
    def externalModuleDir = properties.getProperty('occ.dir', null)
    if (externalModuleDir == null) {
        throw new GradleException(
                "OpenCascade location not found. Define location with occ.dir in the local.properties file!")
    }
    return externalModuleDir
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '.so'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

Inside `local.properties` add below snippets.

```
sdk.dir=D\:\\Software\\android_sdk
ndk.dir=D\:\\Software\\android-ndk-r12b-windows-x86_64\\android-ndk-r12b
occ.dir=D\:\\Workspace\\OCCT\\inc
```

For `OcctJniActivity.java` remove `freeimage`. replace `TKJniSample` with

```
     // application code
     || !loadLibVerbose ("OcctJni_Viewer",  aLoaded, aFailed))
```

**NOTE** :

1. Use latest gradle experiment for the sample.
2. Don't forget to add Shaders in assest folder. Others are not required for this sample
3. I have used OCC 7.0.0 and latest Android Studio.

I am attaching [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dt06jkatcr5b5b2/OcctJniViewer.zip?dl=0) and [OCC/include](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1luz4j3hskfmgh4/inc.zip?dl=0) folder.