# Error running Open Cascade example jniviewer for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, opencascade

I tried running open cascade's example "jniviewer" using Android Studio after relying on the following thread with his attached source code at the bottom.

[Opencascade Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349139/opencascade-android-studio)

After building the project, I have trouble running it on a Nexus S emulator (tried different ones as well) as I get the following error:

> Launching app
>
> The currently selected variant "arm7-debug" uses split APKs, but none of the 1 split apks are compatible with the current device with density "240" and ABIs "x86".
> Error while Installing APK

I'm new to gradle/ndk and any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Joel